# Append to data in an XML attribute using Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, xml

Newbie alert!

I am trying to automatically append some text to the data within an XML attribute - I believe notepad++ will do it but I cant figure out the expression I need to use to search.

It should be fairly straight forward so I hope someone can help - here is my original:

```
<Name>MY DATA</Name>
```

and i wish it to have the word _FR appended to the end so it looks like this:

```
<Name>MY DATA_FR</Name>
```

Any assistance you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think REGEX is not necessary, you have an option Replace (CTRL-H) in Notepad++.

In this new window you put "DATA<" in the "search for field" and then put "DATA_FR<" in the "replace with" field.

After that you have buttons for search, replace and replace all on the right hand for searching and replacing.
This suggestion assumes that you do not have MY DATA attributes which you do not want to replace.

Comment: Thank you ryder.  That certainly does the trick, however the data inside the <Name> </Name> attributes will be different in different XML sheets so I need to be able to tell it to append the _FR to whatever is in between them, regardless of the words.  Ultimatley I am trying to automate this process with a macro that does the same search everytime and always appends _FR to the data.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Notepad++:

```
Find what:    <Name>(.+)</Name>
Replace with: <Name>\1_FR</Name>

Regular expressions is ON
```

EDIT: Just in case, here is a [comprehensive post](http://letconex.blogspot.nl/2013/06/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in.html) on regular expressions in N++, some useful examples are at the bottom.